# Ceate folders for AD users using a CSV file produces wrong folder names

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have created a CSV file listing certain Active Directory users. Now I want to use this CSV to create a certain amount of folders for those users. I started with

```
$UserList = Import-Csv .\users.csv
```

and continued with

```
ForEach ($UserName in $UserList) {
  $UserName
  New-Item -Name $Username -ItemType directory -Path .\Download\$UserName
  New-Item -Name $Username -ItemType directory -Path .\Home\$UserName
  New-Item -Name $Username -ItemType directory -Path .\Publishing\$UserName
}
```

What I expect is that each folder `Download`, `Home` and `Publishing` contains a subfolder having the username, e.g. `testuser`.
When I run this script, the result for the folder names is `@{name=testuser}` which is not the expected result.

Any ideas how to solve this naming problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to dereference the property.

If you run this:

```
$UserList = Import-Csv .\users.csv
$UserList[0]
```

You should see something like this:

```
name
----
testuser
```

The `name` heading there tells you it's a property of the object `$UserList`.

For the solution, you could do this:

```
ForEach ($User in $UserList) {
$UserName = $User.Name
$UserName
New-Item -Name $Username -ItemType directory -Path .\Download\$UserName
New-Item -Name $Username -ItemType directory -Path .\Home\$UserName
New-Item -Name $Username -ItemType directory -Path .\Publishing\$UserName
}
```

Or this:

```
ForEach ($User in $UserList) {
$User.Name
New-Item -Name $Username -ItemType directory -Path .\Download\$($User.Name)
New-Item -Name $Username -ItemType directory -Path .\Home\$($User.Name)
New-Item -Name $Username -ItemType directory -Path .\Publishing\$($User.Name)
}
```

Or, alternately, you could get just the names on import like this:

```
$UserNameList = Import-Csv .\users.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

ForEach ($UserName in $UserNameList) {
$UserName
New-Item -Name $Username -ItemType directory -Path .\Download\$UserName
New-Item -Name $Username -ItemType directory -Path .\Home\$UserName
New-Item -Name $Username -ItemType directory -Path .\Publishing\$UserName
}
```

However, if there are other values in your CSV file that you want to use, this last option isn't a good solution because you're *only* importing the name.